# AngularJS UI-events binding doesn't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angularjs

I'm using angular-ui and ui-events module and ui-map but the thing is that the event binding aren't working.

**HTML**

```
<div id="map" 
     ui-map="myMap"
     ui-options="mapOptions" 
     ui-events="{'map-click': 'addMarker($event)'}"
     class="map-canvas">
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myAppModule', ['ui.map'])
.controller('CtrlGMap', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-54.798112, -68.303375),
        zoom: 11,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    $scope.myMarkers = [];

    $scope.addMarker = function($event) {
        $scope.myMarkers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.myMap,
            position: $params[0].latLng
        }));
    };

}]);
```

I know that ui-map loads the ui-events module. But nothing happens when I click on the map :(

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure on this - but you might only be able to use $event in conjunction with ng-click